# Socket connection on the client side

Tags: java, sockets

I have a  questions that is perhaps indicative of my lack in experience and the fact that I am still a student.

I established a socket connection client side(server is already running) and after making the connection on the client side I immediately go to a different Form(that is also based on the client side) where I want to verify userName and password against database on the server side. Problem is, I feel that I do not want to make the connection again as I have already done this on the previous Form

clientSocket = new Socket(hostAdress, 7777);

How can I 'carry over' the fact that I have a connection already to the new form so that I just create and input and output stream without making the connection again on the new form.

Sorry, hope this question makes sense

Kind regards

Arian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method like this:

```
public Socket getSocket() {
    return clientSocket;
}
```

and call it from the other class (assuming that you have a reference to that object.

Answer (score 1):

or static variable:

```
private static Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostAdress, 7777);
```

and as Binyamin wrote, create a method , but in this case it would be static method